# Trouble connecting with friend in Minecraft Pocket Edition demo

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I both have the same Minecraft Pocket Edition demo. It has always worked for connecting in multiplayer, but all of a sudden, my friend can't connect to my server and I can't connect to theirs. It just sits at the "scanning for servers" for hours. Anyone know what to do to fix it?

We are using the same wifi. Both are on iOS and using the same version, I think. We haven't updated anything (not the phones or the game). There hasn't been any changes to the wifi recently.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem too..
But i worked it out. Try to update McPeDemo to 0.7.5 or Install McPeFull.

Otherwise -----

*Hosting a server and Make your friends play it is not really a proper way of playing.
Fix: Try to start a game, make your friends play, tap multiplayer or play, wait till it scans, and voila your friends can see your personal world.